# Set decimal value to certain value based on underlying number with t-sql case when

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, decimal, case, rounding

How to set the decimal values to a condition based value for underlying number using case when in T-Sql? Example to clarify:

Column **SalesPrice** is used for prices (2 decimals), like 129.99 or 19.99 for example.

I would like to select SalesPrice, but with a slight adjustment in the result:

- If SalesPrice >= 100 the decimals should be .00 (129.99 --> 130.00)
- If SalesPrice <  100 the decimals should be .95 ( 19.99 -->  19.95)

Thanks!

Comment: Um... your rounding rules aren't clear, when do you round up and when do you round down?

Comment: Good question, if 12.01 --> 11.99, if 12.51 --> 11.99, if 12.95 --> 12.95, if 12.96 --> 12.95. Hope this is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all values are positive, here is one approach:

```
update t
    set SalesPrice = (case when SalesPrice >= 100 then floor(SalesPrice) + 1
                           when SalesPrice < 100 then floor(SalesPrice) + 0.95
                      end)
    where (SalesPrice - floor(SalesPrice)) >= 0.9;
```

I added the `where` clause so this only affects prices where the decimal amount is greater than 0.90.  That way, prices like `15.49` are not affected.  You can adjust this to your needs.  If you wanted to affect all prices with decimal values, then:

```
update t
    set SalesPrice = (case when SalesPrice >= 100 then floor(SalesPrice) + 1
                           when SalesPrice < 100 then floor(SalesPrice) + 0.95
                      end)
    where SalesPrice > floor(SalesPrice);
```

The `where` clause guarantees that there is a decimal amount.  This prevents `21` from turning into `21.95` for instance.